React MUI Table - hidden overflows it wrapper
I'm encountering an issue with the Material-UI table in my project, particularly on mobile screens.
Although the table itself resizes and scrolls horizontally correctly, both the table element and its contents extend beyond the page, seemingly disappearing off to the side.
Here's a image demonstrating the problem:
enter image description here
import {
  Paper,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableContainer,
  TableRow,
} from '@mui/material';
import { FC } from 'react';
import { useStyles } from './useStyles';
import TableHeader from './TableHeader';
import TableContentBody from './TableContentBody';

interface TableProp {
  data: any;
  caption?: string;
}

const CsvTable: FC<TableProp> = ({ data, caption }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper} sx={classes.tableContainer}>
      <Table sx={classes.tableStyle}>
        <caption>{caption}</caption>
        <TableBody>
          {data.map((row: any, index: number) =>
            index === 0 ? (
              <TableHeader data={data[0]} key={index} />
            ) : (
              <TableRow key={`row-${row}-${index}`}>
                <TableContentBody row={row} columnsNames={data[0]} />
              </TableRow>
            ),
          )}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
};

im using 5.14.11 version of mui/material
Thanks in advance :)
I've attempted to resolve this by adjusting the width within all relevant wrapping components, but unfortunately, this hasn't fixed the issue.
I've also tried to Create a div container with overflow: auto, then another container with: width: '100%', display: 'table', tableLayout: 'fixed' but it didn't worked.
While the table view adjusts according to the width, it seems as though there's an underlying layer of content that remains present but transparent. Additionally, I've confirmed that deleting the tables from the page eliminates the problem, so I'm certain the issue lies there.
